# How to configure settings in Django when realative reference of static files don't contain a 'static'?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbee to html/js/css.

Now I have a big frontend that use realative reference of static files that don't contain a 'static' prefix.

[image]

However Django need a STATIC_URL definition in settings.py, default is "/static/".

Then the real request url is "/demo/faces/male/16.jpg", but the url django expected is "/static/demo/faces/male/16.jpg"

[image]

It's really a big frontend maintained by other guys, I don't want to modify it.
Is there a method to remove the 'static' requirement?

Comment: Did you try to set `STATIC_URL = '/'` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: If I set STATIC_URL = '/' ,it raise a error "Directory indexes are not allowed here."

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Try `STATIC_URL = ''`

Comment: @JonhyBeebop It raise "You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting." . I'm using django 2.x on Python 3.6, really thx for your reply.

Comment: Are you sure you want Django to serve these static files during development?  Talk to your frontend guys, they might have a better solution..

Comment: Thx. I modified the frontend with django template {% static %} finally.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/). It says "In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files."

The example that they give puts `static` in the specification of the additional directory, but that appears to be inessential. So you would just list your `/demo/faces/male` and `/demo/faces/female/` directories.

Comment: Thx. I modified the frontend with django template {% static %}  finally.